# HighCharts Scatter plot: How to change legend symbol for each series

Tags: highcharts

I have requirement - For Series 1, user circle legend symbol & for series 2, use diamond legend symbol. How to force / set this in highcharts ?

Comment: You can set [marker symbol](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.marker.symbol) for partical serie. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/h9Lf2duy/

Comment: I will try this @sebastian bochan

Comment: @SebastianBochan: It works but did not fit for my case. I had used differnet way. In cofig settings i handled it by specifying 'symbol' property same like you did

Comment: @SabastianBochan: Can we specify color for legend symbol ? Any idea on this

Comment: @SO19 - please look at the documentaion here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<scatter>.marker

Comment: @SebastianBochan - I will check on that